# How to apply filter on array of Object in angular js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter

I have an object of Student with names and other properties. I need to filter based on the name. Name will be passed as input text box. How to do it in angular.js

```
$scope.Students = [ {Name:'David', id : '1010', Age: '20'} ,{Name:'John', id : '1020', Age: '21'} ,{Name:'Scarlett', id : '1020', Age: '21'} ]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can filter using the $filter from angular js

```
var value = $scope.studentname;
var selected = $filter('filter')($scope.Students, {Name: value}, true),env;
$scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.SelectedStudent = selected[0];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const students = [ 
    {Name:'David', id : '1010', Age: '20'},
    {Name:'John', id : '1020', Age: '21'},
    {Name:'Scarlett', id : '1020', Age: '21'} 
]

const data = students.filter(function(item){
    return (item.Name === 'David');
});

console.log('data value: ', JSON.stringify(data));
```